# awt Robot does not work correctly on Ubuntu 21.04

Tags: java, awt, awtrobot, ubuntu-21.04

It seems that something happened after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 21.04. Maybe this process has not had enough rights or maybe something else but I can't figure out what's wrong. I wrote some simple code for executing `alt tab` but nothing happens. I'm using `OpenJDK corretto-15.0.2`. This code worked correctly on Ubuntu 20.04 but now it doesn't.

```
var robot = new Robot();
        
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
Thread.sleep(100);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
```

Note: When I try to perform click `alt` and `tab` separately it works fine.

Comment: `Thread.sleep(100)` Shouldn't the code use [`Robot.delay(int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/Robot.html#delay(int)) there instead?

Comment: tried with ``robot.delay(100);`` still not work...

Comment: Also, I detected that I can enter combinations like alt+2 but alt+tab does not work.