# Unable to click ALT+TAB programmatically ubuntu 21.04

Tags: python, keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-21.04

I'm trying to understand why I am no longer able to perform alt-tab and other manipulations programmatically on Ubuntu 21.04. I thought that smth wrong with `awt.Robot` from java but this functionality does not work for python too. So I guess this functionality won't work at all. Did something change from a security perspective?
I'm using Kernel 5.11.0.40-generic

here is an example from python

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller, KeyCode
import time


keyboard = Controller()


keyboard.press(Key.alt)
keyboard.press(Key.tab)
time.sleep(1) 
keyboard.release(Key.tab)
keyboard.release(Key.alt)
```

[java examplte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70033605/)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: specific problem: I can't perform alt-tab from code. I can't create a program in any language to do it. I already have a program that works fine on Ubuntu 20.04  but it no more works in Ubuntu 21.04